# How to change location for mpdf

Tags: yii2, mpdf, kartik-v

In **Yii2 *kartik-v version 7.0* mpdf**, I am trying to change location for saving temporary files as required. Where should I edit to change the location?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

from MPDF yii2 docs

`tempPath:` string, the folder path for storing the temporary data generated by mpdf. If not set this defaults to `Yii::$app->getAlias('@app/runtime/mpdf')`.

you can set like this

```
$pdf->tempPath = Yii::getAlias('@web/runtime/mpdf/');
```

http://demos.krajee.com/mpdf#settings

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I already set tmp location here, but still it try to store in mpdf folder directly. Dont know why it not store to specified location